# Float select field caret to left (bootstrap 4)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, bootstrap-4, css-float

Is it possible to float the select field bootstrap caret to the left?

[image]

I tried the below but did not see a change

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    float:left !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this <kbd>First Run code snippet</kbd>

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <span class="dropdown-toggle pl-4 pt-2" role="link" style="float:left;"></span>
</div>
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: Sure, there must be some inheritance would happening in your source, So if you share the source, it could be easier for any body to find the issue.